# Can i use PL2303 USB to TTL Serial Converter Module send keystrokes using Arduino nano?

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, usb, keyboard

If I can, which library to use (an example code will be great).
Here is the module:
[image: PL2303 USB to TTL Serial Converter Module]

Comment: Like Majenko said in their answer.  If you don't want to get a board with native USB support for whatever reason, and want to use your Nano, the easiest thing is to have the Nano pretend to be a PS/2 keyboard, at which point you're likely using a PS/2 to USB adapter, rather than a logic level serial to USB adapter.  Odds are good that you can acquire a USB to PS/2 adapter locally from someone that has old computer junk, assuming you don't just happen to have one yourself.

Comment: it may be possible ... research `FreePIE` ... https://andersmalmgren.github.io/FreePIE/

Comment: @timemage, how?

Comment: @Juraj, you want me to write an article in the comments about how to make a Nano behave like a PS/2 keyboard?

Comment: @timemage, more about how to convert it to USB signal. but now I realized what you mean.

Comment: @Juraj, in my comment "PS/2 to USB adapter" refers to [this sort of thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port#/media/File:Usb_to_ps_2_adapter_IMGP1414.jpg), in case that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is serial. Just like every other USB to TTL Serial converter. The clue is in the name.

You need an Arduino with a dedicated native USB interface, like those based on the ATMega32U4 chip.

Or dedicated software on the PC that will read serial data and emulate keypresses (which is outside the scope of this website).

Comment: Is there any module that lets me do this

Comment: I posted something to that effect in a comment on your question itself.  Had it been worded differently, I might have put it as an answer, or part of one.  Now that you *have* an answer *addressing what you actually asked*, you should avoid changing the nature of the question though.

Comment: @WHITE_DEVIL yes there is. It's called an Arduino based around the atmega32u4.